# App In Billing: Alpha Test - After bought item, is possible to check if item is purchased? In Aplha test mode

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing

My in app billing is working normal with my tests.

But using my item SKU and after a success purchase on ALPHA test mode seems that my check if the item was purchased is not working.

**Someone knows if the check if an item was purchased works on APLHA tests?**
Because seems to me that the purchase is fake on ALPHA test and is not being registered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works the same way in alpha and beta versions. It must be a problem somewhere in your code. I suggest to check this doc: [Testing In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

You can also utilize static IDs for testing IAP, i.e:

`android.test.purchased`

> When you make an In-app Billing request with this product ID, Google
>   Play responds as though you successfully purchased an item. The
>   response includes a JSON string, which contains fake purchase
>   information (for example, a fake order ID). In some cases, the JSON
>   string is signed and the response includes the signature so you can
>   test your signature verification implementation using these responses.

Comment: Using 'android.test.purchased' it works as normal operation. But using my own registered ITEM_SKU the purchase works but the check on inventary if the item was purchased does not seems to work. Should my own ITEM_SKY purchase check whether is it purchased or not works on ALPHA?

Comment: Yes it should work on alpha/beta builds. You have to upload this version to Play Store and wait some time, it may take several hours to update.

Comment: Yes it works on ALPHA and BETA tests. The problem was that the ITEM_SKU at Google In App Products page was INACTIVE. I only ACTIVATED it on website and it worked.